# How to add an element to JSON Laravel pagination object

Tags: php, json, laravel, pagination

With this request:

```
$apps = DB::select("select 
        a.id, a.app_name, a.country_id, a.feature_id, a.organization_id, a.status_id,
        o.organization_name, f.feature_name
        from apps as a
        left join organizations as o on o.id = a.organization_id
        left join features as f on f.id = a.feature_id
        order by app_name
        ");
    
    $apps = DB::table('apps')->orderBy('app_name')->paginate(10);
    return response()->json($apps);
```

I get this json:

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "ab221e40-e711-11e8-b124-95a6d9405f4b",
        "app_name": "Asf autre",
        "country_id": "FR",
        "feature_id": "5724ecad-f8d3-3b5f-bd36-d62e97a26798",
        "organization_id": "44720e79-eaf9-300a-bbcd-cdfce46dbf54",
        "status_id": "PROD",
        "created_by": "6d2aeca8-a29d-38b0-bbd7-8f0c9656ca3b",
        "updated_by": null,
        "created_at": "2018-11-13 07:59:30",
        "updated_at": "2018-11-13 07:59:30"
    },
    {
        "id": "f4ccb480-e711-11e8-a6e6-3b8112548306",
        "app_name": "Asf pays",
       .....
```

Perfect.

I would like to add some keys in each element of the "data" key. To have this kind of json:

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "akeyhere" : "avaluehere",
        "id": "ab221e40-e711-11e8-b124-95a6d9405f4b",
        "app_name": "Asf autre",
        "country_id": "FR",
        "feature_id": "5724ecad-f8d3-3b5f-bd36-d62e97a26798",
        "organization_id": "44720e79-eaf9-300a-bbcd-cdfce46dbf54",
        "status_id": "PROD",
        "created_by": "6d2aeca8-a29d-38b0-bbd7-8f0c9656ca3b",
        "updated_by": null,
        "created_at": "2018-11-13 07:59:30",
        "updated_at": "2018-11-13 07:59:30"
    },
    {
        "akeyhere" : "anothervalue",
        "id": "f4ccb480-e711-11e8-a6e6-3b8112548306",
       .....
```

How would you do that? I think I must use "ressources" notion but I never used that and I tried without success.

Comment: Use the `$append` variable on the model and an accessor https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json (remember that this only work if you cast models to json, raw queries wont work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are casting **objects** to json, you can use the `$append` variable in the model and an accessor like this:

```
// Get your data using eloquent to retrieve models

$apps = App::orderBy('app_name')->paginate(10);

return response()->json($apps);
```

And on your model you add:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class App extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['akeyhere'];

    public function getAkeyhereAttribute()
    {
        return 'avaluehere';
    }
}
```

If you want to stick with **raw queries** or the **query builder** you have a couple of options aswell:

~ **Iterate** the result and append the desired elements.

```
$paginator->getCollection()->map(function ($element) {

    $element['akeyhere'] = 'avaluehere';

    return $element;
})
```

~ **Hydrate** the result set and then cast it to json

```
$apps = DB::table('apps')->orderBy('app_name')->paginate(10);

$apps = App::hydrate($apps);

return response()->json($apps);
```

This will turn a result set of arrays into models, so you could now take advantage of the `append` feature.

*IMO* you are best taking advantage of the model features Laravel provides, so if I were you I would go with the first option.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi Asur, thanks for your answer. I prefer keep using query builder. I understand the iteration you speak about. But how to iterate though the "data" key of this json ? I tried without success. DOm

Comment: Thanks Asur for your help. You saved my day . Merci.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more straigth fordward way of modifying the paginator, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using Query Builder to build your queries, If you want to "automagically" add the property you should use Model Classes, It's basically the same with Query Builder.

```
class SomeClass extends Model {
    protected $appends = ['akeyhere'];

    public function getakeyhereAttribute()
    {
        $data = //data from somewhere
        return $data;
    }
}

SomeClass::paginate(10); //will always include `akeyhere`
```

you can also use [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) to handle your api output better.

Comment: This won't work with OPs current setup, I think you should point it out on your answer

Answer (score 0):

`getCollection()` will return the data section of your collection. You can use  `Laravel` collection function `transform` to update your objects

```
$apps->getCollection()->transform(function($iterator){
  return array_merge($iterator, [
   // add your extra (key, value) here
  ]);
});
```

### Note

This approach suits when you don't want to update your core Models everytime you need an extra value in collection items.

BUT

If it is necessary and you need those extra attribute everywhere with this model you should go with `Custom Attribute` solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-each

```
$apps = DB::table('apps')->orderBy('app_name')->paginate(10);

$apps->each(function ($item) {
        $item->some_key = 'some_value';
    });

return response()->json($apps);
```